# How to text MYSQL connection in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this connection file..

```
<?php

function OpenCon(){
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "1234";
$db = "enrollment";


$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) ? die("Connect failed:       %s\n". $conn -> error);

return $conn;
}
function CloseCon($conn)
{
$conn -> close();
}

?>
```

and another php file..

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

But an error occured

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\enroll\index.php on line 4

please help me how to fix this error..thank you

Comment: this is my connection php file<?php
 
function OpenCon(){
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "1234";
$db = "enrollment";
 
 
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) ? die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);
 
return $conn;
}
function CloseCon($conn)
{
$conn -> close();
}
   
?>

Comment: this my index.php file.. <?php
include 'dbcon.php';

$conn = OpenCon();

CloseCon($conn);
 
 ?>